# Get the substring that is in between two strings php

Tags: php, string, split, substring, explode

suppose i have a set of strings formatted in a way:

```
$string1 = "(substring1) Hello";
$string2 = "(substring2) Hi";
```

how do i get the inside of '()' as a single string. I know this is possible by
using:

```
$substring = explode( ")",$string1 );
```

but then i'm left with **$substring[0]** containing **"(substring"**, and **$substring[1]** containing the rest. Is there a fast wat to get the **inside of '()'**? thanks i know it's a no brainer question.

Comment: Just a note. `explode` is used when you want to split a string into multiple parts. What you want here is to *extract* **one string** from **another string** according to a certain pattern. Thus `preg_match(_all)` is the way to go. Hanky Panky's answer is exactly how I would have solved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode` might need a workaround because `(` and `)` are different. A simple regex will get the job done.

```
$string1 = "(substring1) Hello";
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $string1, $match);  // preg_match_all if there can be multiple such substrings
print $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to keep the explode, do this with your substring[0]:

```
$substring[0] = substr($substring[0],1);
```

this will return you the portion after "(".

Else, use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match what you need!

Edit:

Check the above answer to see the regular expression solution, this guy provided you a great way to solve your problem! :]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `explode` to do this job:

```
<?php
$string1 = "(substring1) Hello";

function between($delimiter1, $delimiter2, $subject)
{
    $arr = explode($delimiter2, $subject);
    if (!$arr || empty($arr) || count($arr) == 1)
    {
        return '';
    }
    $oldStr = trim(array_shift($arr));
    $arr = explode($delimiter1, $oldStr);
    if (!$arr || empty($arr))
    {
        return '';
    }
    return trim(array_pop($arr));
}

$result = between('(', ')', $string1);
echo $result, "\n";
```

But I suggest you use `preg_match` function, which is use regular expression to match string, more powerful and complicated:

```
<?php
$string1 = "(substring1) Hello";

$pattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';
$match = array();
preg_match($pattern, $string1, $match);
echo $match[1], "\n";
```

Comment: `more powerful and complicated:`: Is that really more complicated? That regex seems so simple as compared to that `complicated` explode code